# Create a URL based on SpringSecurity username in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf

Using the Thymeleaf SpringSecurityDialect I am able to display the username of the logged in user like this:

```
Logged in user<span sec:authentication="name">Username</span>
```

I'd like to go one step further and use that loggedin username to generate a URL.

```
<a href="view.html" th:href="@{'/view/'+${user.username}}" />
```

I have been doing this so far by adding this directly to the model, however I was wondering if it was possible to do this directly just using the SecurityDialect and tags.

For instance in JSP it would be trivial to add this to a pagecontext var.

```
<sec:authentication var="user" property="principal" />
```

However, I I'd like to know if there's an option for me to do something like this in thymeleaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using ${#authentication.name} in stead of ${user.username}? It should work...

```
<a href="view.html" th:href="@{'/view/'+${#authentication.name}}" >TEST</a>
```

[You can find variety of examples here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity)